# Having issues logging out state variables in Hardhat unit test

Tags: erc-20, hardhat, testing

I am currently trying to log out the inherited **_allowances** state variable from a contract that inherits OZ's ERC20Upgradeable contract within Hardhat:

```
mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) private _allowances;

let result = await myToken._allowances();
```

However, the CLI is complaining that `myToken.allowances` is not a function. Can anyone advise why this isn't working? Perhaps an issue with the syntax? I've logged out state variables before so not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here

**1.** In your solidity code, the mapping is set as `private`. Use `public` instead.

`mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public _allowances;`

**2.** Your Hardhat syntax for `_allowances` is missing input variables "addresses".

**Example:**

`let result = await deployed.transferManager._allowances(owner.address, account2.address);`

Answer (score 0):

you have defined your `_allowances` mapping as private. You should marked as public, however, remember that you can not query all allowances at once, you would have to pass both addresses to receive the allowance.<

Hope it help